# How do I prevent a line of white pixels when using PIL to create an image from a binary array?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am writing some code that takes a list of lists whose entries are either 1 or 0 and outputs a black and white image with pixels defined by the 1s and 0s.

Here's the important bit of the code I've tried:

```
im = Image.new('1', (width, length))
pixels = im.load()

for i in range(im.size[1]):
    for j in range(im.size[0]):
        pixels[j,i] = array[i][j]
        print(array[i][j])
        print(pixels[j,i])
im.show()
```

This works when I type out a test list manually, but when I take the list generated by an earlier part of my code I get a line of white pixels along the top, and a few other strange artefacts. The print parts of my code show that the issue is happening at this point, no matter what value array[i][j] gives, for the first row pixels[j,i] gives 1. Printing my full array also gives me what I expect, it's just the image that's wrong.

Any idea what could be causing this? Or how to fix it?

Comment: Are you saying that even if `array` contains nothing but zeros, the image will have a white stripe? And the `print` matches the image?

Comment: I tried generating an array only of zeros... and curiously my image was ALL white as opposed to all black. The print gives an array full of zeros as expected. Again, if I give it a manually typed out array of all zeros, I get an all black image as expected. It's only when I use my code to generate it.

Comment: My code is for a stochastic 1D cellular automaton, the first line is randomly generated and the next lines are supposed to be evolutions of the first line. Could it have something to do with the first line generation? `array.append(np.random.choice((0, 1), p=[1 - genP, genP]))`

Comment: Can you provide an example of generated array causing the problem?